# JDepend for hierarchical packages?

Tags: java, package, jdepend

I'm interesting in limiting dependencies from one package to a package hierarchy. For example, specify com.a.package and do not allow dependencies to:

```
com.a.package
com.a.package.subpackage
com.a.package.subpackage.subpackage
```

The JDepend appears to support adding all of these individually; has anyone found a way to specify a package tree?

Thank you